# Is it possible to search Google Images using latitude and longitude for a web app?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, google-image-search

I'm working on a web application to find images taken in a given location. I'd like to be able to do this using the latitude and longitude retrieved from geolocation to match geotagged images in Google images.

Is this possible? I've searched around a bit; it seems it's possible to search Flickr by lat/long, but I haven't found anything that indicates I can search Google images by lat/long. I can search by place name, but I'm looking for something more accurate than that.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: With the Google Maps API, it looks like I can get a list of photos back from a "places search" and then ask for place details, but that's not quite the same thing as I'm asking, which is to be able to search (via the API or URL) using lat/long.

Answer (score 1):

After looking through [Google's Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/) (the Google Image Search API was deprecated and rolled into it), it looks like there isn't a way to search by geolocation.

Flickr might be your best bet since it's more open.

Answer (score -2):

It's possible to retrieve images and photo taken at a certain place (therefore find a place by lat-long data) with Google Earth. While you are on a specific place, you can add additional layers (by default) including photos on your location.